# Kubuntu 14.04 change login animation/splash screen

Tags: kubuntu, 14.04, login-screen

In kubuntu 14.04 settings there is the option for changing the login screen background, but there is no more the option to custimise the animation/splash screen after the login, while the desktop environment loads.

Is there any way to change/customise it like in Kubuntu 12.04?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I sort it out myself... the splash settings window can be opened launching the "ksplash" application typing ALT+F2 and then "ksplash", or searching "ksplash" in the search box of the application menu.